# How to make a view controller appear and dismiss through a modal segue from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with connecting a modal segue with a view controller.

In my storyboard, I have a uicollectionview controller connecting a modal segue to a table view embedded in a uiviewcontroller.

The table view contains "filters" to filter the cells in my collection view.

So far I have been able to load the view controller when the user clicks on a button in an action sheet, which opens when the user clicks a bar button item called "more"

**PICTURES**

**My collection view:**

[image: my uicollectionview]

**The UIActionSheet:**

[image: UIActionSheet]

**My Filters View Controller**

[image: filters view controller]

So the problem I am having is when I click the "filters" button in the action sheet, it loads the filters view controller, and when I press the "cancel" button, I am able to close the view controller from my collection view. However, when I press the "Done" button, my collection view disappears.

**My Code**

**MainViewController.m (Collection view)**

```
-(void)openActionSheet {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"What else would like to do?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"About Backpack", @"Filters", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];


}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Filters"]) {
        [self showFilters];
    }
}


#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self applyFilters:[NSSet setWithObject:searchBar.text]];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchText length]) {
        self.dataSource = self.originalDataSource;
        self.imageData = self.originalImageData;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark FiltersViewControllerProtocol

// "Done" button
- (void)filtersSelected:(NSSet *)filters {
    [self hideFilters];
    [self applyFilters:filters];
}

//"Cancel" button

- (void)filterSelectionCancelled {
    [self hideFilters];
}


#pragma mark private

- (void)showFilters {

    if (!self.fvc) {
        self.fvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"filters"];
        self.fvc.delegate = self;

        _fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:_fvc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}

-(void)hideFilters {

    [_fvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)applyFilters:(NSSet *)filters {
    NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *s in _dataSource) {
        for (NSString *filter in filters) {
            if ([s rangeOfString:filter options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {

                [newData addObject:s];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < newData.count; i++) {
        NSInteger loc = [self locationOfItemGivenName:newData[i]];
        backpackIcons *item = _backpackItems[loc];
        [newItems addObject:item.image_url];
    }


    self.dataSource = newData;
    self.imageData = newItems;

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)locationOfItemGivenName:(NSString *)name {
    NSInteger found = -1;
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < _backpackItems.count; i++) {
        backpackIcons *item = _backpackItems[i];
        if([item.name isEqualToString:name]) {
            found = i;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

**FiltersViewController.h (filters table view)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol FiltersViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)filtersSelected:(NSSet *)filters;
- (void)filterSelectionCancelled;

@end

@interface FiltersViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FiltersViewControllerProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

**FiltersViewController.m**

```
#import "FiltersViewController.h"

@interface FiltersViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *selectedRowObjects;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *filters;

@end

@implementation FiltersViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedRowObjects = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:10];
}

- (IBAction)filtersSelected:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate filtersSelected:self.selectedRowObjects];
}

- (IBAction)cancelFilterSelection:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate filterSelectionCancelled];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *obj = cell.textLabel.text;

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedRowObjects removeObject:obj];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedRowObjects addObject:obj];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
@end
```

**Another problem I have having is that the filters table view is not loading my cell labels as well.**

I appreciate all help. Thanks to anyone who can!

Comment: What "Done" button? I don't see one in your images.

Comment: My bad, I meant the "Save" button

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? Did you try logging filters, newData, and newItems inside applyFilters: to see what they contain?

Comment: I don't have a problem with that. My problem lies in the fact that the cell's label has no text to display, even though I specifically coded it to do that. I have used the filters method with a searchBar and it has worked, so there is no problem there.

Comment: You said that your collection view disappeared. Do you mean it's just not displaying anything in its label? Do you see the cells?

Comment: no I don;t see anything at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57959/discussion-between-varun-iyer-and-rdelmar).